# C# string within dynamic object passed to constructor

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, .net-4.5

I have a class like below

```
public class TzTimeZone
    {
        public TzTimeZone()
        {   
        }

        public TzTimeZone(string timeZoneId, string timeZoneName)
        {
            this.TimeZoneId = timeZoneId;
            this.TimeZoneName = timeZoneName;
        }

        public string TimeZoneId { get; set; }

        public string TimeZoneName { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm trying to create an instance of this class using the constructor by passing a string within a dynamic object. The dynamic object "result" contains 2 properties - timeZoneId and timeZoneName.

If I instantiate this class using the below syntax, I get an execution time error (it compiles fine). The error message is something like The best overloaded method match for 'TzTimeZone(string, string)' has some invalid arguments

```
var timezone = new TzTimeZone(result.timeZoneId, result.timeZoneName);
```

However, the below works.

```
var timezone = new TzTimeZone { TimeZoneId = result.timeZoneId, TimeZoneName = result.timeZoneName };
```

and the below works too.

```
var timezone = new TzTimeZone((string) result.timeZoneId, (string) result.timeZoneName);
```

Why would this be the case?

My dynamic object comes from here - https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=39.6034810,-119.6822510&sensor=false&timestamp=1331161200

and I read it using the following syntax (using a helper entity service that i wrote) -

```
var result = await entityService.GetEntityAsync<dynamic>(url);
```

Comment: If you cast them to a string does that work as well?

Comment: What are the types of `result.timeZoneId` and `result.timeZoneName`?

Comment: They are both strings and yes, casting does work. My question is how come it is able to infer when the automatic properties are set without casting but passing it to the constructor requires an explicit cast?

Comment: Perhaps the compiler doesn't want to make that kind of assumption because of the dynamic object?

Comment: Works for me with `dynamic result = new { timeZoneId = "CST", timeZoneName = "Central Standard Time" };`. Something's different with your dynamic object. Where did it come from?

Comment: `dynamic result = null; var timezone = new TzTimeZone(result.timeZoneId, result.timeZoneName);` compiles just fine for me with your class.  Please provide a *complete* program that demonstrates the problem you are describing.

Comment: Can you post the definition of result, because as @TimS. said this compiles and runs.

Comment: Sure, my dynamic object comes from this. I have also added more details to the question how I read this - https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=39.6034810,-119.6822510&sensor=false&timestamp=1331161200

Comment: That is strange, I reproduce the code, but have no issues with that.